# Power BI exception for page level filters

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the page level filter `sales_type=1`, however there is one visual on this page, where I need the `sales_amount` of `sales_type=2`.

I tried the following DAX Measure:

```
sales_amount_type_2 = CALCULATE(SUM(SALES[sales_amount]), ALL(SALES[sales_type]), FILTER(SALES[sales_type]=2))
```

showing no result. The two conditions are probably conflicting. Any ideas how to do it right?

Answer (score 3):

You have applied a page level filter sales_type=1, which means for this page you have data only where sales_type=1. This is so logical that any visual from this page will not get data for sales_type = 2.

Regarding filtering, there are 3 type of filter as stated below-

1. Report level filter: Filter data set for whole report (all pages, all visuals).
2. Page level filter: Filter data for the specific page (all visuals in this page) where the filter implemented.
3. Visual level filter: Filter data for the specific visual only.

Now, in your case you have applied a page level filter sales_type = 1. So any visual inside this page will receive data only where sales_type = 1. As your Measure applying aggregation where sales_type = 2, this is logical that no results are showing.

Finally, to resolve your issue -

**Option-1:**
you can remove the page level filter and apply that filter in other visuals or in specific visuals where it is basically required.

**Option-2:**
You can create your measure as below-

```
sales_amount_type_2 = 

CALCULATE(
    SUM(SALES[sales_amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(SALES),
        SALES[sales_type]=2
    )
)
```